# VBA read/search text file

Tags: vba, excel

I’m trying to read a text file that has 1147 lines. The code below is only reading lines 1050-1147. My goal is to read the entire file and pull out the specific values located on various lines to use within a script. An example would be the value 2 from the line containing “BlockList: 2”. I've included a snippet of the format of the text file as it's formatted differently than any example that I've come across (lines 1116-1128); The values I'm trying to access are indented the same as the first line shown (not sure if that matters).

```
    fixation.OffsetTime: 426611
    *** LogFrame End ***
Level: 2
*** LogFrame Start ***
Procedure: TestProc
BlockList: 2
BlockList.Cycle: 1
BlockList.Sample: 2
Running: BlockList
*** LogFrame End ***
```

Level: 1
*** LogFrame Start ***
Experiment: ChoiceofLotteries_fMRI_I

The code so far:

```
Sub OpenTextFileTest()
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
    Dim fs, f, contents, var1
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\NameOfFile.txt", 1)
    contents = f.ReadAll
    f.Close
    Debug.Print contents
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (*An example on how to extract the value of `BlockList:`*)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Replace this with the relevant file
    Open "C:\NameOfFile.txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        If InStr(1, strData(i), "BlockList:", vbTextCompare) Then
            Debug.Print Split(strData(i), ":")(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

The Text file that you have is `Unicode` text File and hence you are getting that problem. If you do a `SaveAs` and then select `ANSI` in the encoding and then run the above code, does it work?

Click [here](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/reading-txt-files-from-vba/) For an alternative way of [reading txt files using VBA](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/reading-txt-files-from-vba/)

Comment: Hi Siddharth, Thanks for the quick response. I ran the script and nothing displayed within the immediate window per the line Debug.Print Split(strData(i), ":")(1). I included the line Debug.Print MyData after the line Get #1, , MyData and it appears that it's still only reading lines 1050-1147. Another issue came to mind as well. The name BlockList would be a header if this were an excel file and the values under the "headers" change throughout the text file. I'm trying to figure out how to get, say, blocklist value one, blocklist value two, etc.

Comment: Is the data actually separated by a line feed? Any chance I can see the txt file?

Comment: Also before this line `Debug.Print Split(strData(i), ":")(1)` put this line `Debug.Print strData(i)` Do you get anything?

Comment: Still nothing after inserting the statement. I can send you the file if you'd like. I can't seem to locate an email on your profile.

Comment: you can upload it in www.wikisend.com and share the link here :)

Comment: Oh, that's cool. Here's the link http://wikisend.com/download/901180/example.txt . I wont be able to get back to you until tomorrow as I have to leave for a meeting. Good luck and thank you.

Comment: Found the problem :) Updating the post above

Comment: Hi Siddharth, Thank you for taking a look at that. The script is reading more of the file, but not all of it. After running it multiple times I'm finding that it's reading different ranges of lines. It's always going to the end of the file but the "start point" or first record in my immediate window fluctuates